# How to get the Vue module in helper function / mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js in development.

I use the `cookie-universal-nuxt` for getting cookie in severside and clientside

```
modules:[
  [.....] ,
  [.....] ,
  [.....] ,
  ['cookie-universal-nuxt', { alias: 'myCookie' }],
]
```

And I have a helper function

```
// helper.js
const func = {
  getSomthingFromCookie(check){
    return this.$myCookie.get('check') === check ? "something" : "else"
  }
}

export default func
```

```
// another functions

const mixin = {
  methods: {
 getSomthingFromCookie(check){
    return this.$myCookie.get('check') === check ? "something" : "else"
  }
}
}
Vue.mixin(mixin)
// use this.getSomthingFromCookie outside
```

then use it in the store or some pages

```
// Page.vue or store.js
<div>{{ helper.getSomthingFromCookie("test") }}</div>
..
..
..
..
..
import helper from '~/function/helper.js'


OR

const result = helper.getSomthingFromCookie("test")
```

But it return:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I think it is because the `helper.js` cannot access the vue instance, so it cannot get the `this.$myCookie`.

I tried to `import Vue from 'vue'` and `console.log(Vue)`
But the logs in terminal like

```
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
    { install: [Function] },
```

Therefore, I'm not sure that can I get the `$myCookie` function in imported `Vue`.

I know that I can fix this by getting `getSomthingFromCookie.get('check')` outside and pass it back to the function like:

```
getSomthingFromCookie(check,cookie){
    return cookie === check ? "something" : "else"
  }
```

But this is not efficiency and need to change many codes. 
Any better solutions or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `helper.js` file you do not have access to the `vue` instance using `this` binding. You have to explicitly import Vue.

```js
// helper.js
import Vue from "vue";

const func = {
  getSomthingFromCookie(check){
    return Vue.$myCookie.get('check') === check ? "something" : "else"
  }
}

export default func
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not work in client side : Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

Comment: It works on server side?
can you console log the `Vue` instance in client side?